# Can't define a new symbol into IEC in autocad Electrical

Tags: cad

I got this library (see Image), online, that contains objects for household electrical components, and I am trying to make each object as a symbol into my IEC library but I can not do it. I tried [this link here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-electrical/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-add-a-an-icon-to-the-symbol-library-menu-in-AutoCAD-Electrical.html) but nothing happened. And I tried using symbol builder but can't add into IEC library, because it browse file into JIC or Pneumatic or Hydraulic.
So anyone can give me a method to save every object in the picture as a symbol and use it always in an IEC library.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer here [in this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cG9LFsFuUoo). but thanks for all of you anyway.